Order a Pointcloud2 that has a height of 1
(ROS2 HUMBLE, GAZEBO CLASSIC 11.10),
I am using the gazebo "libgazebo_ros_camera.so" plugin with type "depth" to receive a Pointcloud2 message, it works but the problem is that the PointCloud2 message is not ordered (the pointcloud2 message has a height of 1), it seems like the plugin is unable to produce an ordered pointcloud or am i missing something?
        <gazebo reference="depth_camera_link">

            <sensor name="depth_camera" type="depth">
                <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
                <always_on>true</always_on>
                <visualize>true</visualize>
                <update_rate>30</update_rate>
                <camera>
                    <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
                    <image>
                        <width>1280</width>
                        <height>720</height>
                        <format>R8G8B8</format>
                    </image>
                    <clip>
                        <near>0.05</near>
                        <far>8.0</far>
                    </clip>
                    <noise>
                        <!-- <type>gaussian</type> -->
                        <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
                            That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
                            channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
                        <!-- <mean>0.0</mean> -->
                        <!-- <stddev>0.007</stddev> -->
                    </noise>
                </camera>
                <plugin name="depth_camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
                    <frame_name>depth_camera_link_optical</frame_name>
                    <min_depth>0.05</min_depth>
                    <max_depth>8.0</max_depth>
                </plugin>
            </sensor>
        </gazebo>

Is there any library that can order an unordered PointCloud2 ros message?
Thanks.
